# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find : No such file or directory - caused by makefile error

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Good day.

I am attempting to compile a vulnerable vsftpd version for a University assignment. I'm having troubling compiling the source code onto the lxc container launched to host the vulnerable ftp server. The following message is spat at me when I attempt to execute the make command:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find : No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:24: vsftpd] Error 1
```

Despite my many years writing code I am quite new to C++ in general, however I gather this might have something to do with line 24 of the Makefile, which is highlighted below:

```
# Makefile for systems with GNU tools
CC  =   gcc
INSTALL =   install
IFLAGS  = -idirafter dummyinc
#CFLAGS = -g
CFLAGS  =   -O2 -Wall -W -Wshadow #-pedantic -Werror -Wconversion

LIBS    =   `./vsf_findlibs.sh`
LINK    =   -Wl,-s, -lcrypt

OBJS    =   main.o utility.o prelogin.o ftpcmdio.o postlogin.o privsock.o \
        tunables.o ftpdataio.o secbuf.o ls.o \
        postprivparent.o logging.o str.o netstr.o sysstr.o strlist.o \
    banner.o filestr.o parseconf.o secutil.o \
    ascii.o oneprocess.o twoprocess.o privops.o standalone.o hash.o \
    tcpwrap.o ipaddrparse.o access.o features.o readwrite.o opts.o \
    ssl.o sslslave.o ptracesandbox.o ftppolicy.o sysutil.o sysdeputil.o


.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $*.c $(CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS)

vsftpd: $(OBJS) 
    24th line >>>> $(CC) -o vsftpd $(OBJS) $(LINK) $(LIBS) $(LDFLAGS)

install:
    if [ -x /usr/local/sbin ]; then \
        $(INSTALL) -m 755 vsftpd /usr/local/sbin/vsftpd; \
    else \
        $(INSTALL) -m 755 vsftpd /usr/sbin/vsftpd; fi
    if [ -x /usr/local/man ]; then \
        $(INSTALL) -m 644 vsftpd.8 /usr/local/man/man8/vsftpd.8; \
        $(INSTALL) -m 644 vsftpd.conf.5 /usr/local/man/man5/vsftpd.conf.5; \
    elif [ -x /usr/share/man ]; then \
        $(INSTALL) -m 644 vsftpd.8 /usr/share/man/man8/vsftpd.8; \
        $(INSTALL) -m 644 vsftpd.conf.5 /usr/share/man/man5/vsftpd.conf.5; \
    else \
        $(INSTALL) -m 644 vsftpd.8 /usr/man/man8/vsftpd.8; \
        $(INSTALL) -m 644 vsftpd.conf.5 /usr/man/man5/vsftpd.conf.5; fi
    if [ -x /etc/xinetd.d ]; then \
        $(INSTALL) -m 644 xinetd.d/vsftpd /etc/xinetd.d/vsftpd; fi

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.swp vsftpd
```

Despite my researching I do not understand how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Line 24 --> `... -o vsftpd $(OBJS) $(LINK) $(LIBS) $(LDFLAGS)` all is defined in the vars section except `LDFLAGS`. Check this `Makefile` and see if copying the `LDFAGS` section  helps: https://fossies.org/linux/misc/vsftpd-3.0.3.tar.gz/vsftpd-3.0.3/Makefile

Comment: @DavidRanieri Ah, upon further inspection it seems that the script used to get the libraries this version depends upon doesn't check the upddated locations for libraries such as the pam librar and crypt library. I think modifying the makefile and inserting a most recent revision of the vsf_findlibs.sh script shall render more promising results.

Comment: First, please show the compile or link line that caused the error, not just the error message, when asking for help.  Second, it's almost 100% certain that you want the `LDFLAGS` to come before the `LIBS` variable in the link line.  Third, I suspect that this is wrong in your `LINK` variable: `-Wl,-s,`.  There should not be a trailing comma here, it should just be `-Wl,-s`.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the `libmysqlclient` should resolve this issue. On Ubuntu, run:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```